# Wordpress error and extreme slow site on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress

In the admin panel there is often an error like this:

```
Warning: Can't connect to http://wpmlorg.s3.amazonaws.com/wpml-products.json in /Users/adri/Documents/websites/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/inc/installer/includes/installer.class.php on line 441
```

or something like:

```
Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /Users/adri/Documents/websites/htdocs/wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php on line 83
```

In some cases there are more lines like this and in all cases the sitepress-multilingual-cms plugin is involved.

I have installed the P3 profiler plugin and it reports that there is a huge time lap on woocommerce multilingual cms plug-in. I'm not sure if I can disable this plugin and still be able to translate the necessary strings to WPML.

The site is for now on my localhost. I have tried to figure out if there is a DNS issue involved but my knowledge is not sufficient.

I'm aware that all of this sounds a bit vage but I hope that there is somebody out there who dare to take the challenge ;-)

Any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a plugin that connects to external source? This might not be your server but something else connecting to external services. such as disquess, google analytcis or something like these...

Comment: Thank you for commenting. There are several plugins installed. WPM, SEO by Yoast, etc. Those plugins are installed this week and the problem is from an earlier date. I was not able to figure it out but it is realy annoying. It also occurs on the dashboard when opening the installed plugin page for instance. On other pages it occurs as well. Silly enough are there moments that it is quite quick enough to work with.

Comment: can you install wordfance plugin and scan your wordpress for hacks..

Comment: @Erdem, thank you. The site appears to be clean. However I changed some things in my settings. The WPML plugin has the ability to keep track of strings that has to be translated. Switching this option off (and on, only when needed) did good for the performance. Second I changed the Debug mode in wp-config.php from true to false (and true when needed). This also gives the speed a boost. So I think I solved the issues for now. In any case, thank you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a quote from the OP in a comment.

> I changed some things in my settings:
>
> 1. The *WPML plugin* has the ability to **keep track of strings** that has to be translated. **Switching this option off** (and on, only when
>      needed) did good for the performance.
> 2. Second I **changed the Debug mode in wp-config.php** from true to **false** (and true when needed). This also gives the speed a boost. So I think I solved the issues for now.